# Unity Hub crashing on startup (black screen) because of missing projects

Tags: unity

My Unity Hub is suddenly refusing to open. The first time I launch it I get an error message:

> The Hub as [sic] encountered a critical error and must close.
> You can report a bug using our bug reporter tool

Reporting the bug seemingly does nothing, unless it sends the telemetry in the background with no visual feedback. Launching the Hub again opens a black window.

I have some projects on a network attached drive that I am not always connected to. The last lines of %AppData%\UnityHub\logs\info-log.json are related to one of those projects:

```
{"timestamp":"2022-08-19T16:20:17.526Z","level":"error","moduleName":"App","message":"[\n  \"Failed to start Unity Hub, reason: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\\\\\\\192.168.0.202\\\\[path to project]\\\\hubInfo.json'\"\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-08-19T16:20:17.526Z","level":"error","moduleName":"App","message":"[\n  \"Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\\\\\\\192.168.0.202\\\\[path to project]\\\\hubInfo.json'\"\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-08-19T16:20:17.527Z","level":"error","moduleName":"ErrorBox","message":"[\n  \"EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\\\\\\\192.168.0.202\\\\[path to project]\\\\hubInfo.json'\\n\" +\n    \"Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\\\\\\\192.168.0.202\\\\[path to project]\\\\hubInfo.json'\"\n]"}
```

but there is also the following error:

```
{"timestamp":"2022-08-19T16:20:16.441Z","level":"error","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[\n  \"Failed to connect to pipe: 'Unity-LicenseClient-[my Windows username], pid: undefined'\"\n]"}
```

I've seen forum posts about Unity Hub not launching when external drives containing projects are disconnected, so I am suspecting my NAS setup to be the culprit here. My questions are:

- Does Unity Hub really break if a project you opened once is no longer available? Or is my issue the licensing thing?
- Is there a workaround? Maybe making the Hub "forget" the project... which I think you can do in the GUI... but... well you get the issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that

> Unity requires the use of memory-mapped files to work correctly, which in some operating systems doesn't work well or at all over network shares; due to that, opening projects from network shares is not supported. [[source]](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/cannot-create-a-new-unity-project-in-a-shared-network-folder-with-r-slash-w-access)

[This thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-does-not-launch-critical-error-encountered-v-3-0-1-2022-manually-solved.1250809/) in the Unity forums has a solution that worked for me (thanks to DMGregory for sharing the thread as a comment!). You can make Unity Hub forget about your network shared project with the following steps:

> 1. Open Registry Editor (search it in your start menu)
> 2. Find the folder called
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Unity Technologies/Unity Editor 5.x
> 3. Find RecentlyUsedProjectPaths (Be informed that there can be multiple if you have many projects on your Hub's list
> 4. Double click or Right Click/Modify to see its path which matches the one that caused the error and delete it
> 5. Try to launch again, if it does not work, re-install Unity Hub too.

I agree with the poster of the thread that this issue resulting in a fatal crash is very weird, and at the very least Unity should warn that projects on network shares are unsupported.